# how to Multiply 2 columns from different tables but same database mysqli php

Tags: php, mysql, multiplication

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "zoo");

if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    echo "Failed to connect" . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sel = "Select * from animal where quantity";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sel);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo "<tr>";
    echo"<td>" . $row['quantity'] . "</td>";
}
$qsel = "Select * from price where bill";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $qsel);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['bill'] . "</td>";
}
?>
```

how to Multiply 2 columns from different tables but same database mysqli php

Comment: add more details

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "zoo");

if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    echo "Failed to connect" . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sel = "select (quantity* bill) as total from animal inner join price on animal.id=price.animal_id group by price.animal_id";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sel);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo "<tr>";
    echo"<td>" . $row['total'] . "</td>";
}
```

Before copy and paste check your table relation column name and update accordingly.

Comment: Okay. @B.Desai for your suggestions.

Comment: @buttercup. thats why I told check the relation column from both table. send me both table structure. I will make query for you.

Comment: Just paste here tables along with columns.

Comment: @buttercup tam talking about columns name.

Comment: your database structure is not good. You can not multiple values without any relationship? you are missing something here.

Comment: The tables you are making(price table) is price of animal or something else? Price should be specific animal right?

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will give you whole result without manipulation in php.

```
select (quantity* bill) as total from animal inner join price on animal.id=price.animal_id group by price.animal_id;
```